# Pytorch DataLoader changes data types

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-geometric

I am getting started with Pytorch and Pytorch-geometric. I have found that using the recommended built in `DataLoader()` class to batch my data changes the underlying data type.

I would like to structure my code as follows:

1. import data.
2. move data to mps/gpu and correct the datatypes.
3. Split into training and test sets.
4. Build my model and execute my training loop.

Instead, I've found that I have to correct the datatypes of my input data inside my training loop, which seems really inefficient. It also seems like I must be doing something wrong.

Specifically, I'm using a built-in dataset from `torch_geometric` that has datatype `torch.LongTensor`. I manually update it to `torch.FloatTensor`, and then pass it into a `DataLoader()`. However, when I examine the batches generated by the `DataLoader()`, I see that the data type has reverted back to `torch.LongTensor`. The following code block should replicate the error:

```
import torch
import torch_geometric
from torch_geometric.datasets import MoleculeNet
from torch_geometric.loader import DataLoader

#Load dataset
dataset = MoleculeNet(root = '/tmp/MoleculeNet', name = 'Lipo')

#Check datatype before and after changing
print('DATASET TYPES:')
print(f'dataset.x datatype - before update: {dataset.x.type()}')
dataset.x = dataset.x.type(torch.float32)
print(f'dataset.x datatype - after update: {dataset.x.type()}')

#Create DataLoader
train_dataset = dataset[:100]
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size = len(train_dataset), shuffle = True)

#Look at datatype contained in data loader
print('DATALOADER TYPES:')
for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
    print('before updating dataloader variable')
    print(f'i = {i}, dataloader -> data.x.type() = {data.x.type()}')
    data.x = data.x.type(torch.float32)
    print('after updating dataloader variable')
    print(f'i = {i}, dataloader -> data.x.type() = {data.x.type()}')
```

The output of running this code is:

```
DATASET TYPES:
dataset.x datatype - before update: torch.LongTensor
dataset.x datatype - after update: torch.FloatTensor

DATALOADER TYPES:
before updating dataloader variable
i = 0, dataloader -> data.x.type() = torch.LongTensor
after updating dataloader variable
i = 0, dataloader -> data.x.type() = torch.FloatTensor
```

As you can see, the `DataLoader` produces batches where the x variable is a `torch.LongTensor`, even though the data used to create the `DataLoader` has type `torch.FloatTensor`.